# In Chrome, nested 'span' element inside 'a' element transitions color slower than the rest of the link on hover

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This is a highly specific problem that other people probably won't come across very often. My job has a name that begins with "Mc," and we have some code for the website that automatically makes the "c" in "Mc" small, because our many content creators often get this wrong. The code does this by inserting a span element around the 'c' with a class attached to some styling.

On the site I'm working on now, there's a link with the name in it that is supposed to transition from one color to another on hover. The problem is that this little 'c' transitions slower than the rest of the string inside the 'a' element. However, as I said in the title, this is problem ONLY in Chrome.

I've created a simple jsFiddle that reproduces this issue: https://jsfiddle.net/2z07neyL/2/

Markup:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="/">Work at M<span class="minyC">c</span>Creary's</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Styling:

```
* {
 transition: color 0.15s ease, background-color 0.15s ease;
}

li a {
 color: white;
}

li a:hover {
 color: #bf5700;
}
```

I'm pretty stumped on this one. Getting rid of the minifying code is not an option, neither is removing the transition.

EDIT: When I say I can't remove the transition, I mean I can't remove the transition for the * rule specifically. That rule covers more than this one element.

EDIT2: This problem has been solved, per the comments: https://jsfiddle.net/2z07neyL/6/

Comment: Try targeting your transition to `li a` instead of to `*`.

Comment: I can't do instead of, but I can do in addition to. That transition covers more than this one element, hence the *. That was not my choice, I'm inheriting this code.

Comment: Does adding the specificity help?

Comment: This is what that looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/2z07neyL/5/ . Unfortunately it only works if you remove the * transition rule.

Comment: I think is because `*` is also adding a transition the span. So it is being double delayed. once by the change on its parent, then on its inheritance. Someone with better understanding of the under-the-hood can correct me on this if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah that's it!! All I needed to do was add another transition rule to it with a transition of 0 seconds. So that works like this now: https://jsfiddle.net/2z07neyL/6/ . Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can either do it this way or, for the sake of completeness, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2z07neyL/7/ The span, which inherits the color, will otherwise wait for the parent to complete the transition. Please don't ask me why it's implemented this way! :D

Answer (score 1):

```css
li a {
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.15s ease, background-color 0.15s ease;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #bf5700;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/">Work at M<span class="minyC">c</span>Creary's</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Try this instead.  Here's an updated fiddle link..[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2z07neyL/3/)

Comment: This works, but only if I remove the transition within the *. However, the * rule covers more than this element, so I can't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS instead:

```css
li a {
 transition: color 0.15s ease, background-color 0.15s ease;
}

li a {
 color: white;
}

li a:hover {
 color: #bf5700;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="/">Work at M<span class="minyC">c</span>Creary's</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is causing the problem, but I know how to fix it :)
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/2z07neyL/4/

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', 'a', function() {
  $(this).addClass("trans");
});
$(document).on('mouseout', 'a', function() {
  $(this).removeClass("trans");
});
```

```css
a { color: white; }
.trans {
 transition: color .3s ease;
 will-change: transform;
}
a.trans { color: #bf5700; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/">Work at M<span class="minyC">c</span>Creary's</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```